# With Monit, how do I restart a process when a directory timestamp check fails?

Tags: monit

In my /etc/monit/monitrc I have the following lines:

```
check process foo_server with pidfile /var/run/bwam_server.pid
        start program = "/Users/foo/foo_server.sh start"
        stop program = "/Users/foo/foo_server.sh stop"

check directory foo_data path "/Users/foo/Library/Application Support/foo_server/data"
        if timestamp > 1 minute then alert
        #if timestamp > 1 minute then restart foo_server
```

I know I shouldn't have some of this stuff in my home directory, but this aside:  if I uncomment the last line, Monit tells me `syntax error on foo_server` -- but I am, as far as I understand, correctly defining the process -- how else do I reference it?

Answer (score 2):

add to /Users/foo/foo_server.sh restart action and change config:

```
 if timestamp > 1 minute then alert
 if timestamp > 1 minute then
       exec "/Users/foo/foo_server.sh restart"
```